# Open port 22 in home router, but three computers have the same port open

Tags: networking

If I open the port 22 in my home router so I can connect from the outside and I have three computers behind that router with the port 22 open where would my connection end up? In which of the three computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the router (configuration/software). **In most cases it wont go anywhere.** To have control over it you will need to redirect the traffic from port 22 to a specific IP address from the router settings.